# How can I minimize Visual Studio 2010 to the system tray to save taskbar real estate?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, notification-area

I was wondering if there was a way to run Visual Studio 2010 in system tray? Does anyone know if that's possible?

Comment: What do you mean by „run in a system tray”?

Comment: I mean run a program in system tray, when it's minimized (:

Comment: This doesn't make sense. Just because a program is minimized doesn't mean it will or won't stop working. So, when visual studio is minimized for example during a build, it will continue to build. If this isn't what you mean I suggest you [edit](http://superuser.com/posts/476023/edit) your question

Comment: What I mean is run the program in the System Tray if anyone knows what is that (: Not showing up in the taskbar but in the system tray, where the icons for the battery, network and other stuff is (:

Comment: Why are you trying to achieve this? http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [Tray It!](http://www.teamcti.com/trayit/trayit.htm) to achieve this.

1. Run Tray It! and start Visual Studio.

   [image]
2. Select the Visual Studio process and click the **Place in System Tray!** button.

   [image]
3. Visual Studio is now moved to the notification area:

   [image]
4. Please note that Visual Studio will now **always** minimize to the notification area until you disable this feature again:

   [image]

Answer (score 1):

I think you mean that when you run VS2010, ONLY an icon in the system tray will appear and not hing VS2010-related icons will appear on the taskbar? This is not possible. If VS2010 is running, there will always be a visual effidence of this on the taskbar.

Why don't you want an icon in the taskbar and only in the system tray?

Comment: yeah ... that is what I meant ... I thought I was clear enough ... it's because I have lots of apps running and the whole taskbar it's a mess ((:

Comment: What version of Windows are you using? IMHO is Windows 7 a pretty good version if you want to run a lot of applications at the same time and trying to keep a good overview.

Comment: @Roland: Unlock the taskbar, if locked, and drag it up to create a second row of icons. That unclutters it.